# Evaluate polynomial in specific value

Tags: polynomials

Consider the polynomial function $P: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$,

$$P(n) = \sum_{k = 1}^n k^{10}\:, n = 1, 2, 3 ...$$

Question:  **Evaluate $P(-2)$**

I tried giving $P$ a general form of a polynomial function, but all I found was that $P(1) = 1$, which means the sum of the coefficients is 1.

Comment: Note that the polynomial equation $P(n)-P(n-1)=n^{10}$ holds for infinitely many positive $n$, hence for all $n$. Use this to obtain $P(-2)$ in a few steps from $P(1)$..

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen If $P(n)-P(n-1)=n^{10}$ holds for $n \ge 1$, why would it also hold for $n < 1$ ?

Comment: @Liviu - You call $P$ a polynomial function from $\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$, but the definition you gave only gives values for postive integers. If we accept your word that $P$ actually is a polynomial, then so is $P(x) - P(x-1) - x^{10}$. But that is $0$ for infinitely many $x$, and the only polynomial with more than a finite number of roots is the $0$ polynomial.